# read all files in one directory in python 3 on mac

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I wanna get files list from some path. See my example code :

```py
import os, sys

dirs = os.listdir("⁨⁩/Users/ray/Desktop/inaugural")

for file in dirs:
    print (file)
```

This is error log :

> FileNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         1 import os, sys
>         2 
>   ----> 3 dirs = os.listdir("⁨⁩/Users/ray/Desktop/inaugural")
>         4 
>         5 for file in dirs:
>        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\u2068\u2069/Users/ray/Desktop/inaugural'

Comment: Please edit your post to include more details. Are the files all the same format (e.g. `.csv`)?

Comment: Please try to improve the format (and formatting) of your question. What have you tried already? As a hint: the `\u2068\u2069` in the error hints to the file path being the problem. Look up relative and absolute file paths. (But there will be more errors with your code once this one is fixed. ;) )